# The instance member 'timechanger' can't be accessed in an initializer

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

```
  int timechanger = 10;
  Duration countDown = Duration(hours: timechanger);
```

I am trying to reduce the time with my current time So I have to give a time limit dynamically I have tried this but it shoes error

Answer (score 2):

Just put the static keyword in front of the timechanger.

```
 static int timechanger = 10;
 Duration countDown = Duration(hours: timechanger);
```

Comment: No idea why this has two upvotes. `static` has the *side-effect* of solving this problem. You have no idea whether the OP wants this to be `static` or not...